# How to change default MySQL database/table default COLLATION using WampServer?

Tags: mysql

just want to ask about my problem. My problem is everytime I created a database. It's default collation is always set to '**latin1_swedish_ci**'. But what I want is set this to '**utf8_general_ci**' in **DEFAULT**. I also added this to my my.ini file in mysql:

```
character-set-server=utf8    
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

But it is **default in latin1_swedish_ci**.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-server.html), the `my.ini` is just about the **only** place where you cannot change this setting. You can either:

1. Change the startup parameters - pass `---character-set-server=latin1` etc. to the startup invocation.
2. Recompile with a different default - probably not really practical with WAMP
3. Change the values at runtime. This only changes them for the session though, and is as such rather pointless for these config values.

I'd look into option 1 for a local WAMP machine.